# android - How to know when user speaks into mic during a phone call

Tags: android, voice-recognition

My goal is to be able to get a callback/hook when a user speaks into the mic during a phone call.  I cant use RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH because during a phone call this gets queued until the call ends then the prompt appears.  I need something that while the user is on the phone i can determine if they speak into the mic.  If there is no native way to do this, can you recommend a 3rd party ?

Right now im using android noiseAlert sample code and it looks like this:

```
public class SoundMeter {
    static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private double mEMA = 0.0;

    public void start() {
        if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mRecorder.start();
            mEMA = 0.0;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null)
            return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
        else
            return 0;

    }

    public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
        double amp = getAmplitude();
        mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
        return mEMA;
    }
}
```

What is a good measurement i can use to know that the user is speaking into the mic using this approach ?  for Example can i do the following:

```
SoundMeter soundMeter = new SoundMeter();
soundMeter.start();
if(soundMeter.getAmplitude>1.0)
//users is talking into the mic
```